# Como logearse con facebook usando firebase en android studio

Tags: android-studio, firebase

Estoy tratando de hacer un `login` con `facebook` usando `firebase` en `Android Studio`, pero solo puedo hacerlo con la cuenta de desarrollador si lo hago con otra no puedo acceder, me muestra una pantalla de `facebook` diciendo:

> "Necesita permisos de administrador"

El `hash` si lo recibe, si reconoce el id de la `app` pero no inicia con otra cuenta de `facebook`, Aquí esta mi código:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio_sesion);

        //Inicio con facebook
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);

            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button);
            loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email","public_profile"));
            loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                   handleFacebookToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Toast.makeText(InicioSesion.this, "Se canceló", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                    Toast.makeText(InicioSesion.this, "Hubo un error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            listener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                    if ( user!=null )
                    {
                        MainFacebook();
                    }

                }
            };

    }

    private void MainFacebook() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(InicioSesion.this,home.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    private void handleFacebookToken(AccessToken accessToken) {
        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken.getToken());
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if ( task.isSuccessful() )
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(InicioSesion.this, "Algo salió mal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Mi otro `activity`:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView user;
    ImageView foto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        user=findViewById(R.id.user);
        foto=findViewById(R.id.img1);

        FirebaseUser firebeseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if ( user!=null )
        {
            String name = firebeseUser.getDisplayName();
            //String id = firebeseUser.getUid();
            user.setText(name);

        }

    }
}
```

`Permisos de AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

tu  problema parece ser que no has dado los permisos necesarios en tu cuenta de `Facebook Developers` para que tu aplicación sea publica, es decir la configuración de permisos para que cualquiera usuario pueda usar tu `login` debes hacerla en `Facebook Developers` > "nombre de tu `app`" > Revisión de la aplicación, y en letras azules te saldrá `"Añadir permisos y funciones adicionales"`. Para mas información acerca de esto mira la documentación [Revisión de la aplicación](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review).

Comment: trato de hacerla pública, pero esos permisos son para mandar una app a revision y poder subirla google play, y lo que necesito es solo hacerla pública para probar su funcionamiento, sin necesidad de subirla a google play, donde cualquier usuario se pueda loggear :'c

Comment: De allí mismo debes cambiarle el estado de en desarrollo o en prueba a activo, allí en revisión de la aplicación hay una opción que te solicita si deseas que la `app` sea publica, este es el permiso que debes modificar para que cambie de estado. Y sabrás que esta activa por que en la esquina superior derecha te mostrara un mensaje en verde, en vez de gris como seguramente esta.

Comment: Me pide una url, que url iría, si solo es de un proyecto de prueba?